# WP7 PhoneGap application back button exiting application

Tags: windows-phone-7, back-button

I am working on WP7 Phonegap app. I have used below code to handle back button, but whenever I click back button , back button event is not cancelled and application gets exited.

```
        void OnBackKeyPressed(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Dof fd fd  you want to exit?", "Attention!",
                                          MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                // Do not cancel navigation
                return;
            }
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

Please helpme on same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One of the lead devs for the Windows Phone implementation of PhoneGap recently wrote about correctly handling the back button.
See his article at http://www.risingj.com/archives/493

Comment: I have winows 7 app, I added entry to XAML file as well. Method is called and exeuted, but just back event is not cancelled